# Disable Cache in safari

Tags: caching, safari, osx-yosemite

I'm currently trying to develop with Safari (Version 8.0, OS X), and I can't seem to force safari to stop caching my javascript files.

I have tried:

- checking 'Disable Caches' in the Develop dropdown
- symlinking the cache folder to /dev/null
- restarting Safari

None of these have truly disabled the cache, and I am forced to clear the cache every time I want to refresh the page.  This is extremely frustrating and makes development unbearable.

Comment: You could try private browsing... This little-known feature can be enabled by navigating to Safari > Private Browsing. When enabled, you'll see a "Private" tag in the Address Bar. To disable Private Browsing, click the tag.

Comment: @gpullen Just tried this, it seems to work! Thank you.  Although, I still feel there should be a more obvious/permanent solution available

EDIT- Scratch that, just had to clear caches again

Answer (score 0):

Use your server side code to generate your js reference and add a parameter to it so that the browser thinks its a new file every time.

```js
<?php 
$xn = date("YmdHis");

echo  " <script src='root.js?$xn'></script>";
?>
```